# Is there a way to figure out what % of questions on H.SE have accepted answers?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I'm curious what % of questions on H.SE have accepted answers - is there a simple way to figure that out?

Addendum: I know you can view how many unanswered *or* un-upvoted questions there are. I'm interested in how many have an officially accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Advanced search options](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/searching) can help here. As I'm writing this, we have [4,164 questions with an accepted answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+hasaccepted%3A1) and [5,342 questions without one](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+hasaccepted%3A0). So the percentage you're looking for is about 44%.